# iOS bookmark showing favicon instead of apple-touch-icon

Tags: ios, favicon, apple-touch-icon

Can someone tell me more about how iOS prioritizes bookmark icon display and if it's possible to show an icon that's different than the favicon?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting a apple-touch-icon to iOS Safari, it is using this icon for both home screen shortcut and bookmark. More precisely, when running [RealFaviconGenerator's favicon compatibility test](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test), [iOS Safari 9 is using the 180x180 Touch icon in both cases](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).

What to do with your particular issue:

- Bookmark your site again. Like several browsers, iOS Safari does not always take the icon (or the right icon) immediately. Simply repeating the procedure might auto-magically fix the issue.
- Change your favicon code and images to look like ones of RealFaviconGenerator. An easy shot would be to make your Touch icon a 180x180 image, if this is not already the case.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.